# Makefile Compilation Fails When Looking for Library Files, but Only When #include Is Located in Header File

Tags: c++, makefile, compiler-errors, compilation, mingw32

I'm trying to make a minimal reproducible example file to show this problem off- this is how it works and what I am trying to do.

I am attempting to write the word "Applesauce" to a SFML window. There are 4 of my custom-written files- main.cpp, source.cc, header.hpp, and the Makefile. This is what they look like:

main.cpp:

```
#include "header.hpp"

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "My window");
    sf::Font font;
    font.loadFromFile("arial.ttf");

    sf::Text text;
    text.setFont(font);
    text.setString(get_string());
    text.setCharacterSize(24);
    text.setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(text);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

header.hpp:

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H

#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

std::string get_string();

#endif // HEADER_H
```

source.cc:

```
#include "../header.hpp"

std::string get_string() {
    return "Applesauce";
}
```

Makefile:

```
# Compiler
CC=g++

# Flags for the C++ compiler
CXXFLAGS=-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++17

# Include directory for SFML and the header files for your project
INCLUDE=-Isrc -Isrc/include -Iscripts

# Libraries to link against
LIBS=-L src/lib -l sfml-graphics -l sfml-window -l sfml-system

# List of source files
SRCS=main.cpp scripts/source.cc

# List of object files
OBJS=$(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(SRCS))

# Executable file to create
EXEC=applesauce

all: $(EXEC)

$(EXEC): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) -o $(EXEC) $(LIBS)

main.o: main.cpp 
    $(CC) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) -c main.cpp -o main.o

scripts/source.o: scripts/source.cc 
    $(CC) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) -c scripts/source.cc -o scripts/source.o

clean:
    rm -f $(EXEC) $(OBJS)
```

However, when trying to compile the code, I get thrown an error- the Makefile is unable to locate the <SFML/Graphics.hpp> file:

```
PS C:\Users\[My Windows User Name]\Documents\C++ Visual Studio Projects\Headers and Scripts and SFML v4> mingw32-make
g++ main.o scripts/source.cc -o applesauce -L src/lib -l sfml-graphics -l sfml-window -l sfml-system
In file included from scripts/source.cc:1:
scripts/../header.hpp:5:10: fatal error: SFML/Graphics.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:25: applesauce] Error 1
```

An interesting fact is that when I instead have the `#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>` line in main.cpp, the program compiles perfectly fine. This is odd because main.cpp and header.hpp are located in the same directory and I just don't quite understand why it can locate the file in one scenario but not the other.

I'm trying to have `#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>` in header.hpp because I plan on (in my actual program) having functions that require the SFML libraries inside of .cc files.

Any help is vastly appreciated- thank you very much!

Comment: You should have `#include <string>` in header.hpp. If you're setting the include path correctly you shouldn't have a relative directory here: `#include "../header.hpp"`

Comment: @RetiredNinja alright, sure. I've fixed these two.. issues.. but I am still getting the same error and nothing has changed.

Comment: Is that the complete output from make? I don't see the include directives in the command line at all. Don't see the warning and standard either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in these two lines:

```
# List of source files
SRCS=main.cpp scripts/source.cc

# List of object files
OBJS=$(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(SRCS))
```

Because you substitute .cpp but not .cc, the file scripts/source.cc gets included in the build for the executable and thus without the correct flags, as shown by make's display of the command:

```
g++ main.o scripts/source.cc -o applesauce -L src/lib -l sfml-graphics -l sfml-window -l sfml-system
```

Comment: @Game_Freeze Any reason why you don't simply use the same extension for all source files?

Comment: Hold on, I get what you're saying. But I'm not entirely sure how to implement this. Can you give an example?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean, I thought I did..? Always "[filename].cc", right?

Comment: You have main*.cpp* and source*.cc* It doesn't matter which one, but pick one. And then change the makefile accordingly. Using two different extensions is possible of course, but it only complicates the makefile.

Comment: I'm confused what you mean. main.cpp is a C++ file that houses the script execution, and source.cc is just a storage mechanism for functions and variables. It's a source code file. What would you suggest?

Comment: They are both C++ source files.

Comment: Oh yeah you're right, I had no idea. I'll change source.cc into source.cpp then. Doesn't fix my problem but cleaning stuff up is always nice, thanks.

Comment: @Game_Freeze Pretty sure your first comment said it did fix it, but have fun "cleaning up"

Comment: Yeah, it did solve the first problem but it created a new one. I was hoping to solve that one here to avoid explaining the question again in a new thread but I suppose I can do that.

Comment: @Game_Freeze Yes, but that new problem would go away if you do this cleanup.

Comment: Please explain, I'm getting an error that tells me there there's "No rule to make target 'scripts/source.o,', needed by 'applesauce'.  Stop." I'm not entirely sure what I'm supposed to do to fix that.

Comment: @Game_Freeze Be sure to also change every ".cc" in the Makefile to ".cpp"

Comment: Ah welp it was working but now it is not, it cannot find the Graphics.hpp file anymore after I deleted the object files and ran the Make program again. This is very frustrating.

Comment: @Game_Freeze Can you post the output? Specifically the command that make runs; the line above the error

Comment: Yeah totally, it's poorly formatted cuz comment (I tried moving this into a chat but I don't have enough reputation. Argh. I gotta get that up.): PS C:\Users\[My Windows Username]\Documents\C++ Visual Studio Projects\Headers and Scripts and SFML v4> mingw32-make
g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++17 -I -Isrc/include -Iscripts -c main.cpp -o main.o
In file included from main.cpp:1:
header.hpp:5:10: fatal error: SFML/Graphics.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:28: main.o] Error 1

Comment: @Game_Freeze From your own answer, there is a different include than in your question. It should be `INCLUDE=-Isrc/include -Iscripts` The one in the question is fine as well, but not the one you are currently using.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have directory layout like this:

```
SFML
    Graphics.hpp
main.cpp
header.hpp
scripts
    source.cc
```

Correct me if I'm wrong.
Preprocessor searches for `include <>` in the following order:

- standard include paths
- current directory (where the source located)
- project include paths

Order of `include ""` is:

- current directory
- project include paths
- standard include paths

That's why main.cpp causes no problem, but `source.cc` fails, because when it includes `header.hpp`, which includes `SFML/Graphics.hpp`, preprocessor searches relative to `source.cc` location. And obviously can't find it - that's why you get the error.

Add location of `SFML` to include paths and you should be fine.

Comment: (Stack Overflow messed up the formatting on this post, I made a followup comment on its own)

Actually, my directory is structured like this:
```
src 
    include
        SFML
            Graphics.hpp
main.cpp
header.hpp
scripts
    source.cc
```
And my SFML location is inside my include paths-
```
INCLUDE=-I -Isrc/include -Iscripts
```

Just one level up, which is why I reference it like "SFML/Graphics.hpp"

Comment: Yeah it is problematic in comments. Anyway, you need add location of SFML to include search paths (into your `INCLUDE`). ok, just now noticed your 'answer'. Should work :)

Comment: It is there, like I said. "-I src/include" combined with the #include creates "_Isrc/include/SFML/Graphics.hpp", which is the file location for the SFML Graphics.hpp library.

Answer (score 0):

(In response to Noname)
Actually, my directory is structured like this:

```
src 
    include
        SFML
            Graphics.hpp
main.cpp
header.hpp
scripts
    source.cc
```

And my SFML location is inside my include paths-

```
INCLUDE=-I -Isrc/include -Iscripts
```

Just one level up, which is why I reference it like "SFML/Graphics.hpp"